# GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context) is not able to get device id

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was struggling to get device id for my application. Here is my code

This code is from my class

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
device_key = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

This code is from manifest file

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.k2b.kluebook" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I have written `GCMIntentService` class in main package.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME", "gcm");
    ServerUtilities.register(context, "gcm", "gcm", registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("mes");
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    String key = "failed";
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            FragmentOpenActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(key, key);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

}

So many searches are done by me but i cant find solution for this I think many developers are having the same issues but I cant find my mistake in this. Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Do you have any error in LogCat? Did you try with more than one different device?

Comment: I tried in the emulator,bluestack and in android 4.1 also.

Comment: What do you have in your logCat?

Comment: no error or information is not displayed in logcat

Comment: I noticed if the play store is not available or without google login you may not get any registration id from google. Even all are available some times method is not invoking up, like in the onRegister method you are not able to receive registration id.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let me put what I do here:

1. First you have to create Project in Google and get the SENDER_ID.
2. Then, I have this method to registerGCM and call it on OnCreate:

:

```
private void registerGCM() {
        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(getApplicationContext())) {
            String registrationCGMId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        }else{
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
        }
    }
```

If the error persists, check the Google Play app (if it's working normally), the Internet connection or the phone clock time.

Comment: I tried in debug mode thats interesting. First time it skips the if condition and executes else statement then if I comes back and then go to another activity it executes the if condition and shows the device id

Comment: after register only I am able to get the device id before that I was not able to get it

Comment: sure, because the registration is done in background. So if you want to force the device id in the same activity, you will have to check if you already have the device id. In my application, I had a form that needed the device id, so I had to verify the fields and see if I already had the device id..if I didn't, I called the method again to register again untill have the id.

Comment: where should i loop that code. if I recall the `registerGCM()` method in `else` condition my app crashes for first time

Comment: in onCreate you have to put:

if (registrationCGMId == null || registrationCGMId.equals("")) {
   registerGCM();
  }

And you will have to update some info in your onRegistered to avoid registering everytime